# Parsing JSON request body with Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 4.1 framework for developing webservices. When I return a Java object as response, it is automatically converted to JSON and delivered to client, so I assume that JSON parser is in classpath and it is configured properly. However it fails to convert the request body from JSON into Java object and client is getting a HTTP response of 400.

Here is how the webservice looks like:

```
public class Details{
        public Details(){

        }
        int code;
        int area;
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/update/{phoneNumber}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> update(@PathVariable final String phoneNumber, @RequestBody Details details)
```

Here is how the request looks like:

```
Method: Post
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Body: {"code":0,"area":12}
```

If I collect the request body as string and parse it manually then it works, so it gets the valid JSON but for some reason it is not parsing it automatically. I have no clue on how to fix it. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps json converter is not picking up package-private properties. Try adding getters and setters for them in Details class or define them as public. If you are using jackson, you might also annotate them with `@JsonProperty`

Comment: Adding @JsonProperty now gives a response code 415.

Answer (score 1):

You have package-private properties in your `Details` class, so they are probably not recognised by json-converter.

You have several options:

- define them as public (not recommended)
- provide getters and setters
- if you are using jackson, you can annotate them with `@JsonProperty`, leaving them package-private

Comment: Thanks. Tried making them public - No Difference. Adding @JsonProperty now gives a response code 415.

Comment: 415 might pop up while serializing response - are you sure request still does not get inside the method? Try adding breakpoint or some console output at the beginning of the method.

Comment: @Aarkan which version of jackson are you using?

Comment: I am using Jackson 2.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the reason for this. I was using inner classes which were not static. Making those static fixed the issue.